# How to remove tuple from the list if the tuple contains punctuation mark

Tags: python, tuples

I have list of tuple:

```
tupl = [('0', 'Hey'),('1', ','),('2', 'I'), ('3', 'feel'),('4', 'you'), ('5', '!')]
```

I want to remove any tuple containing a punctuation mark.

I already tried with the following code, but it is working for `'!'`, only because I don't know how to put multiple condition in this code.

```
out_tup = [i for i in tupl if '!' not in i]
print out_tup
```

How can I remove all tuples containing punctuation marks (e.g. `','`)?

Comment: try to add "and" in the inside conditions. if ' !' not in and ' , '  and etc in i

Comment: out_tup = [i for i in comlist if '!' and ',' not in i] tried this but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `any`

**Ex:**

```
import string

tupl = [('0', 'Hey'),('1', ','),('2', 'I'), ('3', 'feel'),('4', 'you'), ('5', '!')]
print([i for i in tupl if not any(p in i for p in string.punctuation)])

#or
print([i for i in tupl if not any(p in i for p in [",", "!"])])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can change the condition `if '!' not in i` to `if '!' not in i and ',' not in i`.

```
tupl = [('0', 'Hey'),('1', ','),('2', 'I'), ('3', 'feel'),('4', 'you'), ('5', '!')]
out_tup = [i for i in tupl if '!' not in i and ',' not in i]
print(out_tup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `and ',' not in i`

Full code is below:

```
tupl = [('0', 'Hey'),('1', ','),('2', 'I'), ('3', 'feel'),('4', 'you'), ('5', '!')]
out_tup = [i for i in tupl if '!' not in i and ',' not in i]
print(out_tup)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

tupl = [('0', 'Hey'),('1', ','),('2', 'I'), ('3', 'feel'),('4', 'you'), ('5', '!')]
out_tup = [i for i in tupl if not re.search(r"[!,]", i[1])]
print(out_tup) # [('0', 'Hey'), ('2', 'I'), ('3', 'feel'), ('4', 'you')]
```

where

```
r"[!,]"
```

can be expanded with the punctuations you don't want

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
out_tup = [i for i in tupl if not i[1] in [',','!']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the regular expression:

```
import re, string

tupl = [('0', 'Hey'), ('1', ','), ('2', 'I'), ('3', 'feel'), ('4', 'you'), ('5', '!')]
rx = re.compile('[{}]'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation)))
print(list(filter(lambda t: not rx.search(t[1]), tupl)))
```

Output:

```
[('0', 'Hey'), ('2', 'I'), ('3', 'feel'), ('4', 'you')]
```

Demo on [Rextester](https://rextester.com/VGRMA64578).